# Is there a better way to size scaled elements in Xamarin Forms XAML?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scale

This is a snip of XAML from a Xamarin Forms Android application. I am wondering it anyone knows a less baroque way of positioning and sizing a full-width `Slider` which has been scaled to double size?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="auto"/></Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="*"/><ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/><ColumnDefinition Width="*"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Slider Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Scale="2.0" />
</Grid>
```

This is all to get around two bizarre limitations/bugs in XF:

1. The `Scale` parameter is ignored by layout so the slider is sized to double the available space and gets clipped.
2. The `Padding` parameter does not accept relative values so there is no way of specifying I want left and right padding to occupy 25% of the total space available. An absolute number would break on different screen resolution or even on screen rotation.

It seems wildly excessive to have to use a `Grid` for this when I only need one cell!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AbsoluteLayout` to make the code more simple, result will be the same:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Slider
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .5, .5, .5"
        Scale="2.0">
    </Slider>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! That does look better and AbsoluteLayout has some interesting features.

Comment: But XF design is weird! Who'd think of using 'AbsoluteLayout' for a _relative_ layout! And why can't relative values work for all relevant parameters? And who'd want 'Scale' _not_ to be taken into account for layout?